# Is it possible to see if an object inherits IDictionary without generic type parameters?

Tags: c#

I am testing object like this:

```
if (item is IDictionary<object, object>)
```

But that doesn't match all of the other combination of types `<sting, object>, <int, string>` etc...

I just want to know if it has implemented the interface regardless of what generic types it is using.

I found an example that said it was possible doing something like:

```
dictionary.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition == typeof(IDictionary<>));
```

But I still have to specify the type signature or it is not valid.

Is it possible to make a statement that checks the interface without having to specify the type?

Comment: Depending on what your final needs are, if you are trying to find out if you have a Dictionary<T1,T2> and not specifically IDictionary<T1,T2>, you might be able to check for the non-generic IDictionary instead that Dictionary<T1,T2> also implements. This solution will be dependent upon your use case though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close, you really just need to fix up the syntax:

```
dictionary.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
```

Note the `()` after GetGenericTypeDefinition, and the comma inside of the `<>`.

Comment: Ahhrg.  I have been staring at this for so long and I didn't see it. Thanks you!